# Android Sqlite query about sorting

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

my query for sorting employee based on dept is this

```
public Cursor fetchDept(String dept)throws SQLException
{
Cursor c=mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_NAME,KEY_DESGN,KEY_PHONE}, KEY_DEPT + "=" ,new String[]{dept}, null, null, null, KEY_DEPT);
if (c!= null) {
    c.moveToFirst();
}
return c;
```

}

i have passed value from activity class to this query like this

```
   {
        db.open();
        Cursor c=db.fetchDept(dept);

        if (c!= null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            do
            {
            if(dept.equals(c.getString(3)))
            {

        Toast.makeText(this,"found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
            }
            //c.getString(1) +c.getString(2)+ c.getString(4)
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"No dept",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return ;
            }
            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }
```

when running this application gets force close. if any one can help pls do help!
is the passing argument and calling db.query is correct in the above??

Comment: If your app crashes, you should _always_ post the LogCat.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted the LogCat, but there are a few things that jump out at me:

**First,** if you are using the `whereArgs` parameter you need to use the `?` substitution character:

```
Cursor c=mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_NAME,KEY_DESGN,KEY_PHONE},
        KEY_DEPT + "=?", new String[]{dept}, null, null, null, KEY_DEPT);
// You forgot this:  ^
```

(Minor point: you only ask for one `KEY_DEPT` so sorting the results by `KEY_DEPT` is ineffective.)

**Second,** you are asking for the *fourth* column:

```
dept.equals(c.getString(3))
```

but your Cursor only has three columns:

```
new String[] {KEY_NAME,KEY_DESGN,KEY_PHONE}
//  Columns:     0    ,   1     ,   2     ,  no column 3
```

**Third,** [SQLiteDatabase#query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) will always return a Cursor. This Cursor may be *empty* but it won't be `null`. Also your query only returns results where `KEY_DEPT` equals `dept`, so you don't need to check again... Try this code instead:

```
db.open();
Cursor c=db.fetchDept(dept);

// Check any rows that were returned
if(c.getCount() > 0) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"found "+c.getCount()+" matches",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        // Do something extra with each result
    }
}
// The Cursor is empty (No departments does not exist with the name in dept) 
else {
    Toast.makeText(this,"No dept",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

(Don't forget to close your Cursor and Database when done!)

Comment: my database has Five columns namely KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_DESGN,KEY_DEPT,KEY_PHONE but i need only name,desgn,phonebase on dept n given and sort by dept

Comment: But your _Cursor_ only has three and these column are indexed from `0`, so `getString(3)` is out of bounds. Anyway if you still need help, you need to post your LogCat so we can definitely see what is happening and where.

Comment: i have corrected it but now one problem how to order the records using column name and print the records in text view ??